# if i add a return false inside PHP function do i stop execution?

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I was pretty sure that adding a return false in a PHP function it would stop execution ( till today ).

I'm writing a PHP function that check if a file is older than 24 hours to override it.

New file is fetch from an web server via absolute URL, on my local machine i use MAMP and Little Snitch ( a mac firewall ). When i tested the execution of my code, even if the file is less the 24h old i correctly get the "exit script" but i also get a Little Snitch alert that ask me the give PHP permission to connect to the external server.

Is the return false correct to exit function execution?
I don't want that my script keep fetching information from external server each time I fire this function.

sample code

```
function fileUpdate($myfile) {


    if ( file_exists($myfile) ) {   

        if ( time()-filemtime($myfile) < 24 * 3600 ) {

            echo "exit script";
            return false;

        }

    }

    // execute code
    $file = file_get_contents($myfile);

    ........

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thre return statement will stop the execution 
you dont need to use `return false`

Use `return true/false` when you need to check something from function 
Here you can use `return`

After this , function execution will stop , but main thread continues the execution

If you want stop the main thread use `exit()` or `die()`